# Google Search Appliance displays results on the left half side of the web page

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am a newbie to Google Search Appliance(GSA). I would like to display the result of the GSA on the whole web page, but right now it is displayed on the left half section of the web page. Is there any setting in the GSA or GSA defaultfrontend XSLT stylesheet where I can change this display setting of the web page. I might be missing something obvious. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change that from the stylesheet. I think you are asking about changing the width of the search results. Search the following code in the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:if test="$res_cluster_position = 'right'">
  div.main-results-without-dn {
    margin-right: 15.1em;
  }
</xsl:if>
```

You will need to change the value of **margin-right**.